# the present participle for two actions at the same time?

Tags: phrase-meaning, gerunds, present-participles

In order to add an '' ing '' after a comma in a sentence, the events in that sentence have to happen simultaneously? For example :

> She dropped the gun, **putting her hands in the air.**
> **She dropped the gun** and put her hands in the air.
> We lay on the beach, **gazing up at the night sky**
> We lay on the beach and **gazed up at the night sky**

so what about...

> 1. She forgot to tie her shoes,**tripping and falling down the stairs**
> 2. Before writing, Francis had a successful career in horse racing, **becoming champion jockey in 1954.**

As far as I understand, there is no simultaneousness in the last two sentences. What is the logic in these sentences?

Comment: Please tell us the title of the grammar book where you read this rule : … **the events in that sentence have to happen simultaneously**. Perhaps you are thinking of the past continuous tense: While **he was out walking, and thinking** about his problems, he bumped into a friend.

Comment: yes i meant it somehow. because these sentences are not at the same time

Comment: We would still like to know if you read this rule somewhere and what the rule states precisely.  If there's no book, just say you *believed* this rule existed. There are lots of English rules that native speakers believe are true that are complete nonsense.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Streamlining Advanced English and
             The Grammar of the English Tense System Compact Advanced Student's Book Pack

Answer (score 1):

The action described using an 'ing' verb does not have to be precisely simultaneous with a previous action. We may insert 'at once, later, slowly', etc to make any delay clear, but that may not be necessary if common sense suggests that it must have been later.

Clearly, falling down stairs must follow forgetting to tie one's shoes, if that was the cause.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comment. but we saw that in the English grammar books we read, they should always be at the same time. Can you tell me the name of a good grammar book that can explain this subject to me with examples? Or can you explain the logic of this subject ? because this is a topic that really bothers me.

Comment: Can you give the title and author of the book where you found this rule, please?

Answer (score 0):

> In order to add an "*ing*" after a comma in a sentence, the events in that sentence have to happen simultaneously

No, there is no such rule, that is, no rule requiring all uses of a participle form after a comma to be action at the same time. A present participle is a verb form. It describes an action. Usually it is used when an action is closely associate with another action, often at the same time, or shortly before or after the other action. But the association can be of some other sort than being close in time, and a participle can be used in other situations.

But when there is no indication of another sequence of action or other relationship, action at the same time will be assumed, and if this cannot work, the sentence may well not make sense.

Some examples, all of which are grammatically valid and natural:

> - **Putting** one's hands in the air is a symbol of surrender or lack of threat. [*Action of "putting" is not related to any other action.*]
> - She left Florida without a plan, eventually **finding** herself in a small town in Nebraska. [*"Finding" is in a sequence, but not one close in time.*]
> - He left the village at a walk, **jogging** once he reached the high road.
> - The Elbonian Empire became a wold power within fifty years of its foundation, **falling** into decay only 300 years later.
> - The building continued to grow, **rising** at least one story every week.
> - The rain continued to be heavy, **falling** in torrents since the storm started.
> - The author clarified the statement, **discussing** in another chapter when the rule applies.
> - In the absence of recorded usage we must look at related languages, **finding** in Gothic a similar form. [*The relationship is one of similarity, not time sequence.*]

The use of a participle where two actions are close in time is common, but far from invariable. The last two examples in the question are valid and natural.

Any grammar text which presents this as a "rule" rather than a frequent pattern, is either over simplifying or just wrong.

The point made in the [comment by Gotube](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324157/the-present-participle-for-two-actions-at-the-same-time/324161?noredirect=1#comment610532_324161), that  action at or very near the same time is the **default**, assumed when there is no other indication of sequence or relationship, is much more sensible.

Comment: thank you for your comment. and sorry i guess i explained it wrong.The grammar books I read don't always mention that things have to happen at the same time. All of the examples they gave came true in a short time

Comment: There is such a rule, but it only applies when there's no other time expression indicating when the "-ing" event happens. All your example sentences would be nonsense without the time expressions like "eventually", "once he reached the high road", etc. For instance, "*He left the village at a walk, jogging*". This is nonsense.

Comment: @emily Such examples are probably the easiest and simplest to explain, but other uses are possible.

Comment: @gotube I have added 2 examples and clarified my answer

Comment: @DavidSiegel You still claim there's no such rule. I think my nonsense sentence, "*He left the village at a walk, jogging*" shows that there *is* such a rule.

Comment: @gotube I claimn thatn ther is no rule **of the sort described by the OP in the quoted sentence**, that is a rule requiring all uses of a participle after a comma to be  actions at the same time. I point to my new example about gothic, showing the relationship need not be one of sequence at all. But I will clarify the answer further.

Comment: @DavidSiegel It's better, but it really is a *rule*, not a "frequent pattern". The sentence I gave about jogging is simply wrong. It's not a matter of preference or patterns.

Comment: @gotube Consider a variant: "*He left thr village, walking on the grassy path, jogging on the high road*". There is no **time** expression, but the place expression makes it clear the events are not at the same time.

Comment: @emily - 'in a short time' is not the same as 'simultaneously'.

Comment: @gotube Yes, the "walking, jogging" sentence is nonsense, but that does not mean that all such sentences must either be action at the same time, have a time expression, or be nonsense. Other expressions can indicate that the actions are not at the same time. such as **place** expressions. Consider my example about the author.

Comment: @DavidSiegel So the rule exists, but has qualifiers that the quote from the OP's book doesn't indicate. The issue then isn't with the existence of the rule, but with how I've defined the qualifier. It's a semantic rule, not a grammatical one, so anything at all that semantically breaks simultaneity qualifies, including having the subject in a different place. "On the high road" and "in another chapter" both have that effect. I've modified my own answer to reflect this.

Comment: Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries, thereby reducing the blood flow to our hearts and brains. Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries,  reducing the blood flow to our hearts and brains. So what is the difference between these two sentences? @gotube

Comment: @emily Including "*thereby*" emphasizes the cause&effect aspect, but this is still implied here even without "thereby", so the meaning is very similar. Note that here the clogging and the reduction in blood flow occur at more or less the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is correct, but what your book doesn't mention is that it doesn't apply if there's something else in the sentence that indicates you that the "-ing" event did not happen at the same time.

This is usually an expression of time or place. So these following sentences are fine, but without the expressions in brackets, they're nonsense:

> She put on her glasses, reading the first line of text [as soon as her eyes could focus].
> He pulled into the driveway at 4:00, leaving [just moments later].
> They bought a hat on 5th Avenue, finding a matching pair of gloves [in a thrift ship in Soho].

Your first example has nothing to indicate the two events happened at different times, so the sentence means she forgot to tie her shoes while she was tripping and falling down the stairs, which of course is nonsense.

Your other example about Francis makes sense for two reasons. First, "*had a successful career in horse racing*" could be simultaneous with "*becoming champion jockey*". Being a champion jockey is an example of having a successful career in horse racing.

The other reason is the time expression "in 1954". As I said before, the rule about being simultaneous holds unless there's a time expression saying when the "-ing" event happened.

Comment: you explained it very well. So, do you have a recommendation for a grammar book that explains this subject?

Comment: @emily I don't know which books specifically address this exact topic, but everything you need is on this page. There's no more to the rule than what I've written here, and all of David Siegel's examples in his answer show how to use "-ing" expressions with a time expression when the events happen at different times.

Comment: @emily Also, I generally recommend the "Grammar in Use" series of books for self-study. I don't know if they cover this exact topic though.